# Downloading Files with ChromeDriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, download

I have a project where I need to download an audio file in ChromeDriver. The behavior here is different from in regular Chrome, where if I visit the URL, it'll automatically start downloading a file. If I do the same thing manually in ChromeDriver, it will not download the file.

I've tried different configurations of the chrome options/preferences. I've also found options that worked with old versions of chrome, that no longer work anymore.

Here is one of the better resources I found, but it still didn't work, even with their updated blog post
https://dkage.wordpress.com/2012/03/10/mid-air-trick-make-selenium-download-files/

When I attempt to use his solution, my chromedriver abruptly crashes itself in a non chrome-esque way. It just disappears. Not "Something went wrong" page like you'd normally expect. I end up with Java not being able to find my Session, cause it stopped existing.

Has anyone been successful at downloading files through Selenium webdriver in Chrome? If I need to use another browser, I can.

I'm currently using Chrome Canary.

Comment: So you are looking to `downloading files through Selenium webdriver in Chrome` automatically? Can you share an example website and your research please?

Comment: I'm trying to download audio files and perform speech recognition. The latter half is working. The problem I'm having is downloading the file when the page is visited. I can provide a link when I return home

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just download a file via normal I/O instead?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what cookies and factors come into play with the audio. I know that if I were to just take the URL and try it in a new browser, it won't load anything. I can do some experimenting in postman if I have to, to figure out what is required in my request.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. One solution that might work is to use another library, that is able to operate outside of the browser. I found these stackoverflow post discussiong this issue:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver

it contains this blogpost wich gives you some sugestions.
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/

> 1. Window automation
>
> The first approach smells like “brute force”: when searching the net for a solution to the problem, you easily end up with suggestions, to control the native window with some window automation software like AutoIt. Means you have to prepare AutoIt such, that it waits for any browser download dialog, the point at which Selenium is giving up, takes control of the window, saves the file, and closes the window. After that Selenium can continue as usual.
>
> This might eventually work, but I found it to be techical overkill. And as it turned out, there was a much simpler solution to the problem.
>
> 2. Change the browsers default behaviour
>
> The second possibility is to change the default behaviour of the browser. When clicking on a PDF for example, the browser should not open a dialog and ask the user what to do with the file, but rather save it without comments and questions in a predefined directory. To accomplish that, a file download has to be initiated manually, saved to disk and marked as the default behaviour for these file types from now on.
>
> Well, that could work. You “only” have to assure that all developers, hudson instances, etc. share the same browser profile. And depending on the amount of different file types, that could be some manual work.
>
> 3. Direct download
>
> Taking a step back, why do we want to download the file with Selenium in the first place? Wouldn’t it be much cooler, to download the file without Selenium, but rather with wget? You would have solved the second problem as you go. Seems a good idea, since wget is not only available for Linux but also for Windows.
>
> Problem solved? Not quite: what about files, that are not freely accessible? What, when I first need to create some state with Selenium in order to access a generated file? The solution seems ok for public files, but is not applicable for all situations.

Comment: In order to do it through the browser by hand, I need to inspect element, and grab the URL location of the audio file from the code.

I have the option of playing the audio in the browser, and recording it, but that seems to be my overkill solution in mind